# Can I insert objects into tr1 unordered_map

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I have a large amount of data to process in c++ and find that unordered_map works effienct
However, there is no example to stores objects in unorderd_map. When I tried myself it fails to complie.

First I inculde unordered_map

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

then define the type

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<Vector3f, Vector3f> vectorMap;
```

Vector3f here is class I created.
When I complile above it do not returns any error.
However when I add

```
vectorMap _map; 
Vector3f v1,v2,v3;
_map.insert(std::make_pair(v1,v2));
```

complier returns a large paragraph of error, could you please tell me is there something wrong when I insert the pair, or it unsorted doesn't support inserting object, if not, is there any other effient wayin storing and searching objects pairs like hashmap in JAVA. Following is the error message reports in complier:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/string:50,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/iostream:40,
                 from homework1.cc:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::equal_to<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Vector3f]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/tr1_impl/hashtable_policy.h:769:   instantiated from ‘bool std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_code_base<_Key, _Value, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_compare(const _Key&, size_t, std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, false>*) const [with _Key = Vector3f, _Value = std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f>, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<Vector3f>, _H1 = std::tr1::hash<Vector3f>, _H2 = std::tr1::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/tr1_impl/hashtable:918:   instantiated from ‘std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, __cache_hash_code>* std::tr1::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_find_node(std::tr1::__detail::_Hash_node<_Value, __cache_hash_code>*, const _Key&, typename std::tr1::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_Hash_code_type) const [with _Key = Vector3f, _Value = std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<Vector3f>, _H1 = std::tr1::hash<Vector3f>, _H2 = std::tr1::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::tr1::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/tr1_impl/hashtable:983:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::tr1::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::iterator, bool> std::tr1::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::_M_insert(const _Value&, std::tr1::true_type) [with _Key = Vector3f, _Value = std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<Vector3f>, _H1 = std::tr1::hash<Vector3f>, _H2 = std::tr1::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::tr1::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/tr1_impl/hashtable:420:   instantiated from ‘typename __gnu_cxx::__conditional_type<__unique_keys, std::pair<std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<_Value, __constant_iterators, __cache_hash_code>, bool>, std::tr1::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<_Value, __constant_iterators, __cache_hash_code> >::__type std::tr1::_Hashtable<_Key, _Value, _Allocator, _ExtractKey, _Equal, _H1, _H2, _Hash, _RehashPolicy, __cache_hash_code, __constant_iterators, __unique_keys>::insert(const _Value&) [with _Key = Vector3f, _Value = std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f>, _Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _ExtractKey = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const Vector3f, Vector3f> >, _Equal = std::equal_to<Vector3f>, _H1 = std::tr1::hash<Vector3f>, _H2 = std::tr1::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, _Hash = std::tr1::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, _RehashPolicy = std::tr1::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, bool __cache_hash_code = false, bool __constant_iterators = false, bool __unique_keys = true]’
homework1.cc:181:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.5/../../../../include/c++/4.4.5/bits/stl_function.h:203: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__x == __y’
```

This is the Vector3f class

```
class Vector3f {

    float _item[3];

    public:

    float & operator [] (int i) {
        return _item[i];
        }

    Vector3f(float x, float y, float z) 
    {  _item[0] = x ; _item[1] = y ; _item[2] = z; };

    Vector3f() {};


    Vector3f & operator = (Vector3f & obj) 
    {
        _item[0] = obj[0];
        _item[1] = obj[1];
        _item[2] = obj[2];

        return *this;
    };

    Vector3f & operator += (Vector3f & obj) 
    {
        _item[0] += obj[0];
        _item[1] += obj[1];
        _item[2] += obj[2];

        return *this;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your `Vector3f` class has an accessible equality `operator==`, and that `std::hash<Vector3f>` is defined.

For the former, you should probably just go with a member function:

```
struct Vector3f
{
  bool operator==(Vector3f const & rhs) const { /* ... */ }
  //...
};
```

Strictly speaking, all you need is that `std::equal_to<Vector3f>` is defined, but giving your class an equality operator is the most sensible way to achieve this.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie in c++, would you please tell me how to add a equality operator in my class. I will add the class in the question

Comment: @user1069771: Only if you post your current definition of the class! :-)

Comment: @user1069771: OK, simply say `return _item[0] == rhs._item[0] && _item[1] == rhs._item[1] && _item[2] == rhs._item[2];`

Comment: BTW this class is provided by my lecturer as a template and is best not to modify since it is used in the other place in the template. I think the function you mean here likely be Vector3f & operator = (Vector3f & obj)

Comment: @user1069771: If it's "best not modified", then the answer is that you're using a terrible class :-) (In all senses of the word.) You could make a free function instead, `bool operator==(Vector3f const & lhs, Vector3f const & rhs)`.

Comment: [I'm still irate about this: What sort of self-respecting vector class would **not** come with equality comparison? I need to get some fresh air now.]

Comment: when I add bool operator==(Vector3f const & rhs) const {
  return _item[0] == rhs._item[0] && _item[1] == rhs._item[1] && _item[2] == rhs._item[2];
 } it still doesn't work:( How I wish my lecture could publish a template in Java. I'm really tried to learn c++ on almost every aspect in a several days.

Comment: @user1069771: Never say "it doesn't work". **Nobody** can help you with that. Say **what** doesn't work. My bet is that you don't have an implementation for the hash function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5555/discussion-between-user1069771-and-kerrek-sb)

Answer (score 1):

unorderd_map declaration is like

```
template<class Key,
     class T,
     class Hash = hash<Key>,
     class Pred = std::equal_to<Key>,
     class Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> > >  class unordered_map;
```

you have to provide hash and predicate for your custom type Vector3f